# problems with gem (jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) conflicts with jekyll

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

**Good time for everyone!
when I try to start the server, I see a message**

"
Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. If you've run Jekyll with bundle exec, ensure that you have included the jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin gem in your Gemfile as well. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Unable to activate jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin-1.6.0, because jekyll-4.0.0 conflicts with jekyll (< 4.0, >= 2.0)' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
"

**what can be done about it?**

$ jekyll build --trace Configuration file: /home/user/s/villaanna/_config.yml Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. If you've run Jekyll with bundle exec, ensure that you have included the jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin gem in your Gemfile as well. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Unable to activate jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin-1.6.0, because jekyll-4.0.0 conflicts with jekyll (< 4.0, >= 2.0)' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! Traceback (most recent call last): 21: from /home/user/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in '
        20: from /home/user/gems/bin/jekyll:23:inload' 19: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:15:in '
        18: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:inprogram' 17: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in go'
        16: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:inexecute' 15: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in each'
        14: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:inblock in execute' 13: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        12: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:inprocess_with_graceful_fail' 11: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in each'
        10: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:inblock in process_with_graceful_fail' 9: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in process'
         8: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:innew' 7: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:34:in initialize'
         6: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:124:insetup' 5: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:22:in conscientious_require'
         4: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:30:inrequire_gems' 3: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:57:in require_with_graceful_fail'
         2: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:57:ineach' 1: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:58:in block in require_with_graceful_fail'
/home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:73:inrescue in block in require_with_graceful_fail': jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)

**the fact is that I installed "jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin" I can not understand what the problem is my gem list:**

$ gem list

- LOCAL GEMS *

addressable (2.7.0) bigdecimal (default: 1.3.4) bundle (0.0.1) bundler (2.0.2) cmath (default: 1.0.0) colorator (1.1.0) concurrent-ruby (1.1.5) csv (default: 1.0.0) date (default: 1.0.0) dbm (default: 1.0.0) did_you_mean (1.2.0) em-websocket (0.5.1) etc (default: 1.0.0) eventmachine (1.2.7) fcntl (default: 1.0.0) ffi (1.11.1) fiddle (default: 1.0.0) fileutils (default: 1.0.2) forwardable-extended (2.6.0) gdbm (default: 2.0.0) http_parser.rb (0.6.0) i18n (1.7.0, 0.9.5) io-console (default: 0.4.6) ipaddr (default: 1.2.0) jekyll (4.0.0, 3.8.6) jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin (1.6.0) jekyll-sass-converter (2.0.1, 1.5.2) jekyll-watch (2.2.1) json (default: 2.1.0) kramdown (2.1.0, 1.17.0) kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0) liquid (4.0.3) listen (3.2.0) mercenary (0.3.6) minitest (5.10.3) net-telnet (0.1.1) openssl (default: 2.1.1) pathutil (0.16.2) power_assert (0.2.7) psych (default: 3.0.2) public_suffix (4.0.1) rake (12.3.1) rb-fsevent (0.10.3) rb-inotify (0.10.0) rdoc (default: 6.0.1) rouge (3.12.0) safe_yaml (1.0.5) sass (3.7.4) sass-listen (4.0.0) sassc (2.2.1) scanf (default: 1.0.0) sdbm (default: 1.0.0) stringio (default: 0.0.1) strscan (default: 1.0.0) terminal-table (1.8.0) test-unit (3.2.5) unicode-display_width (1.6.0) webrick (default: 1.4.2) zlib (default: 1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved
downgraded version jekyll from 4.0.0 to 3.8.6
jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin not work on 4 version jekyll